# PHP store locator from google example

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I'm trying to get this example from google to work with my code.

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

I'm using the Meekro PHP MySQL library as it facilitates other queries i'm doing.

http://meekro.com/

This is the part that's giving me errors.

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

I'm using the following code:

```
$results = DB::query("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
    $center_lat,
    $center_lng, 
    $center_lat, 
    $radius);
```

I always get the following error using the following parameters:

```
?lat=37&lng=-122&radius=25

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '37'') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(''-122'') ) + si' at line 1
```

Even when I try to run the query in phpMyAdmin I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove quotes arround %s :

```
$results = DB::query("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(%s) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(%s) ) + sin( radians(%s) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < %s ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
    $center_lat,
    $center_lng, 
    $center_lat, 
    $radius);
```

Comment: That solved my problem. Can you explain why it "should" work with google's code but not mine?

Comment: I need to see how you declare variable $center_lat,  $center_lng, and $radius to help you.